# Is $\{a^nb^mc^{n+m} \mid n, m \geqslant 0\}$ a context-free language (CFL)??

Tags: context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

Considering this language $L = \{a^n b^m c^{n+m} \mid n, m \geqslant 0 \}$ is it a CFL? If I can make a PDA for it can I still prove with the pumping lemma that the language is not CFL?
I mean if try first to use pumping lemma to prove that it's not CFL then:

Let $w = uvxyz$, then choose $n = 2$  such that $uv^ixy^iz$
then $uxy$ would have in some cases $a$'s and $b$'s or just $b$'s or just $a$'s or $c$'s anyway if I pump it than $w$ will habe more $c$'s then $b$'s and $a$'s.

So in this case it's still not a CFL?

Comment: A grammar for $L$ would be: $L \to aLc | M, M \to bMc | \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is context free. A grammar for it is:

$$S\to aSc \mid T\\T \to bSc \mid \varepsilon$$

This is because $a^Mb^Nc^{M+N}$ is the same as $a^Mb^Nc^Nc^M$, which means you can build it from the inside out.

Your argument using the pumping lemma doesn't work. Roughly speaking, the pumping lemma says: "If a language is context-free, then every sufficiently long string is pumpable. This means that there exists a number $p$, such that *all* strings in the language longer than length $p$ are sufficiently long.  And for every sufficiently long string, there *exists* a way to subdivide it such that it is pumpable and satisfies all the requirements of the pumping lemma."

In order to show that a language is not context-free, you have to show that:

1. For *every* value of $p$,
2. There *exists* a string $s$ in the language which is longer than $p$, such that
3. For *every possible way* you can divide up the string into $s=\mathsf{uvwxy}$, the string fails to be pumpable:

   Either the string produces results that aren't in the language (so there is some $k\geq 0$ such that $\mathsf{uv}^k\mathsf{wx}^k\mathsf{y}$ isn't in the language.), or the subdivision $s=\mathsf{uvwxy}$ violates one of the pumping lemma rules $|\mathsf{vx}|\neq 0$ or $|\mathsf{vwx}|<p$.

If you can show these steps, you prove that the language is not context-free.  But you cannot use the pumping lemma in an argument like this:

1. I picked a specific pumping length $p=2$ (No; instead, the proof should be for all possible $p$.)
2. I found a string longer than $p$. (Ok.)
3. I chose a specific way to subdivide it (No; instead, the proof should consider *every possible* way to subdivide it.)
4. I found that the subdivision wasn't pumpable. (In order for the proof to be complete, you'd have to show that *every* possible subdivision fails to be pumpable.)